# How do the android.speech package classes work?

Tags: android

In the [`android.speech`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html) package there are some classes for speech recognition. I read [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) and I created a simple application that send an `Intent` in order to start a speech recognition activity: in this way I created an example of speech recognition application and I only used [`RecognizerIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) constants.

Inside the `android.speech` package there are also other classes: why? What are their roles?

For example, the `RecognitionService` class is the base class for recognition service implementations, so *if I wish to implement a new speech recognizer*, then it should extend this class. In this case, what does it mean? Should I use this class if I would implement a new speech recognizer engine without using Google's Voice Recognition engine?

And what about the [`SpeechRecognizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class?